# How To Upgrade "Abp-zero-Template" in .Net Core and Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-boilerplate, abp

I Have been trying this for several days.I am facing an error while up-gradation.I have upgraded all ABP nuget packages and downloaded dotnet core 3.1(SDK) and In Angular, AngularCLI is updated but "abp-zero-template" is not also getting the error in other related ABP modules too.
[Error in Startup.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsPkQ.png)
[Program .cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn9Gi.png) [NGCC Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOqdx.png). 
I have removed node_modules and reinstall it again but still getting the same error

Comment: Were you able to resolve all your issues?